# Determine whether you click on an ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

For a school project I have to draw ellipses and then remove them if I click on them. What formula can be used to determine when the outer line of the ellipse with a margin of 5 pixels is clicked? Or when a filled ellipse is clicked? Clicking on a rectangle is easy but with an ellipse you don't fill the whole space so those corners should not count as part of the ellipse.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: Each ellipse can be defined with respect to two foci and a distance. Check if the clicked point is a certain distance (within a margin of error) that corresponds to the two focal points that are associated with that distance.